# Excel, populating column based on a matrix

Tags: excel

My first table:
list of unique values (Professional designations
) and encoding of values (categories)
.
My second table contains the same values but that can be repeated.

[image]

I would like to encode these values based on the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Cell B12` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A12,$A$2:$B$9,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(A12,$A$2:$A$9,0))
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

Comment: @Wilcar - In case if there's no match found  `IFERROR` will show blank instead of `#N/A`. If there will be a match for sure than you can avoid using it.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Can you add the formula without iferror function in your answer?